# Python - Flatten the list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary, join, list-comprehension

List of dictionaries:

```
data = [{
         'a':{'l':'Apple',
                'b':'Milk',
                'd':'Meatball'},
         'b':{'favourite':'coke',
              'dislike':'juice'}
         },
         {
         'a':{'l':'Apple1',
                'b':'Milk1',
                'd':'Meatball2'},
         'b':{'favourite':'coke2',
              'dislike':'juice3'}
         }, ...
]
```

I need to join all nested dictionaries to reach at the expected output:

```
 [{'d': 'Meatball', 'b': 'Milk', 'l': 'Apple', 'dislike': 'juice', 'favourite': 'coke'},
  {'d': 'Meatball2', 'b': 'Milk1', 'l': 'Apple1', 'dislike': 'juice3', 'favourite': 'coke2'}]
```

I try nested list comprehension, but cannot join dict together:

```
L = [y for x in data for y in x.values()]
print (L)

[{'d': 'Meatball', 'b': 'Milk', 'l': 'Apple'}, 
 {'dislike': 'juice', 'favourite': 'coke'}, 
{'d': 'Meatball2', 'b': 'Milk1', 'l': 'Apple1'}, 
 {'dislike': 'juice3', 'favourite': 'coke2'}]
```

I am looking for the fastest solution.

Comment: [how-to-merge-two-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-to-merge-two-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression) would be helpful.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can do the following, using [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

```
>>> from itertools import chain
# timeit: ~3.40
>>> [dict(chain(*map(dict.items, d.values()))) for d in data]
[{'l': 'Apple', 
  'b': 'Milk', 
  'd': 'Meatball', 
  'favourite': 'coke', 
  'dislike': 'juice'}, 
 {'l': 'Apple1', 
  'b': 'Milk1', 
  'dislike': 'juice3', 
  'favourite': 'coke2', 
  'd': 'Meatball2'}]
```

The usage of `chain`, `map`, `*` make this expression a shorthand for the following doubly nested comprehension which actually performs better on my system (Python 3.5.2) and isn't that much longer:

```
# timeit: ~2.04
[{k: v for x in d.values() for k, v in x.items()} for d in data]
# Or, not using items, but lookup by key
# timeit: ~1.67
[{k: x[k] for x in d.values() for k in x} for d in data]
```

#### Note:

[RoadRunner's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5238915/roadrunner) loop-and-update approach outperforms both these one-liners at `timeit: ~1.37`

Comment: I like your fair behaviour because add timing of another solution which is better, so no reaccepting ;) Thank you.

Comment: @jezrael Thx, nah, no need to hide that fact. It is interesting to compare these 3 stylistically so different approaches and to see that the straightforward loop beats the comprehension and particularly the kitchen sink of built-ins and itertools :)

Comment: A more readable alternative to `dict(chain(*map(...`  is `[ChainMap(*d.values()) for d in data]`. It's slower than the other methods, though.

Comment: Why if I want to flatten the output of  `[{k: v for x in d.values() for k, v in x.items()} for d in data]` which is a list of dictionary it give error `TypeError: descriptor 'items' requires a 'dict' object but received a 'str'`? This result is like the input data.

Answer (score 23):

You can do this with 2 nested loops, and [`dict.update()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update) to add inner dictionaries to a temporary dictionary and add it at the end:

```
L = []
for d in data:
    temp = {}
    for key in d:
        temp.update(d[key])

    L.append(temp)

# timeit ~1.4
print(L)
```

Which Outputs:

```
[{'l': 'Apple', 'b': 'Milk', 'd': 'Meatball', 'favourite': 'coke', 'dislike': 'juice'}, {'l': 'Apple1', 'b': 'Milk1', 'd': 'Meatball2', 'favourite': 'coke2', 'dislike': 'juice3'}]
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) along with a simple list comprehension to flatten out the list the of dicts

```
>>> from functools import reduce 

>>> data = [{'b': {'dislike': 'juice', 'favourite': 'coke'}, 'a': {'l': 'Apple', 'b': 'Milk', 'd': 'Meatball'}}, {'b': {'dislike': 'juice3', 'favourite': 'coke2'}, 'a': {'l': 'Apple1', 'b': 'Milk1', 'd': 'Meatball2'}}]
>>> [reduce(lambda x,y: {**x,**y},d.values()) for d in data]
>>> [{'dislike': 'juice', 'l': 'Apple', 'd': 'Meatball', 'b': 'Milk', 'favourite': 'coke'}, {'dislike': 'juice3', 'l': 'Apple1', 'd': 'Meatball2', 'b': 'Milk1', 'favourite': 'coke2'}]
```

Time benchmark is as follows:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> setup = """
      from functools import reduce
      data = [{'b': {'dislike': 'juice', 'favourite': 'coke'}, 'a': {'l': 'Apple', 'b': 'Milk', 'd': 'Meatball'}}, {'b': {'dislike': 'juice3', 'favourite': 'coke2'}, 'a': {'l': 'Apple1', 'b': 'Milk1', 'd': 'Meatball2'}}]
  """
>>> min(timeit.Timer("[reduce(lambda x,y: {**x,**y},d.values()) for d in data]",setup=setup).repeat(3,1000000))
>>> 1.525032774952706
```

Time benchmark of other answers on my machine

```
>>> setup = """
        data = [{'b': {'dislike': 'juice', 'favourite': 'coke'}, 'a': {'l': 'Apple', 'b': 'Milk', 'd': 'Meatball'}}, {'b': {'dislike': 'juice3', 'favourite': 'coke2'}, 'a': {'l': 'Apple1', 'b': 'Milk1', 'd': 'Meatball2'}}]
    """
>>> min(timeit.Timer("[{k: v for x in d.values() for k, v in x.items()} for d in data]",setup=setup).repeat(3,1000000))
>>> 2.2488374650129117

>>> min(timeit.Timer("[{k: x[k] for x in d.values() for k in x} for d in data]",setup=setup).repeat(3,1000000))
>>> 1.8990078769857064

>>> code = """
      L = []
      for d in data:
          temp = {}
          for key in d:
              temp.update(d[key])

          L.append(temp)
    """

>>> min(timeit.Timer(code,setup=setup).repeat(3,1000000))
>>> 1.4258553800173104

>>> setup = """
      from itertools import chain
      data = [{'b': {'dislike': 'juice', 'favourite': 'coke'}, 'a': {'l': 'Apple', 'b': 'Milk', 'd': 'Meatball'}}, {'b': {'dislike': 'juice3', 'favourite': 'coke2'}, 'a': {'l': 'Apple1', 'b': 'Milk1', 'd': 'Meatball2'}}]
    """
>>> min(timeit.Timer("[dict(chain(*map(dict.items, d.values()))) for d in data]",setup=setup).repeat(3,1000000))
>>> 3.774383604992181
```

Answer (score 4):

If you have nested dictionaries with only 'a' and 'b' keys, then I suggest the following solution I find fast and very easy to understand (for readability purpose):

```
L = [x['a'] for x in data]
b = [x['b'] for x in data]

for i in range(len(L)):
    L[i].update(b[i])

# timeit ~1.4

print(L)
```