# How can I insert element from one dictionary to another based on matching top level key

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of dictionaries  that need to be filled. It has a top level identifier for the Customer Service Case Number. I have another list of dictionaries that has all the email information related to the case - these dictionaries also have the case number that the emails are related to.

I am trying to break up the email list and associate them in the first list of cases.

I am pulling the information using the Simple Salesforce Package.

```
#First dictionary:

Cases =
    [{CaseNumber : "1",
     Date: "value",
     Reason: "value",
     Emails: NONE (need to add here)},
     {CaseNumber : "2",
     Date: "value",
     Reason: "value",
     Emails: NONE (need to add here)}]

#etc.  this list is a set of dictionaries of all the cases related to an order #number that is passed in previously.

#The second list of is a list of all of the emails related to the above cases -

Emails =
    [{CaseNumber : "1",
     Date: "value",
     EmailBody: "value",},
     {CaseNumber : "1",
     Date: "value",
     EmailBody: "value",},
     {CaseNumber : "2",
     Date: "value",
     EmailBody: "value",}]

#So this list needs to get nested accordingly to the Emails key by matching on case number

Cases =
    [{CaseNumber : "1",
     Date: "value",
     Reason: "value",
     Emails: emails[1,2,etc]},
     {CaseNumber : "2",
     Date: "value",
     Reason: "value",
     Emails: emails[3,4,etc]}]
```

Should create a list of nested dictionaries that are related to the top level case Id.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48700710/python-flatten-the-list-of-dictionaries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might not be the *fastest* solution, but I'd go through the emails and group them based on `CaseNumber`. This would be a list of the emails based on that value. From this, you can go through each case, grab the `CaseNumber`, and insert the list into the `Emails` part of the dictionary

```
from collections import defaultdict

e = defaultdict(list)

for email in Emails:
    case = email.get('CaseNumber')
    e[case].append(email)

for case in Cases:
     casenumber = case.get('CaseNumber')
     case['Emails'] = e[casenumber]

# Cases now looks like [{'CaseNumber': '0', 'Emails': [{'EmailBody': 'value'},...], {'CaseNumber': '1', 'Emails': [{'EmailBody': 'value',...}]}]
```

`defaultdict` is a dictionary that will insert a list if a key is not present, allowing for the `e[key].append()` call without checking if the key is in the dictionary. The docs are [here](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

EDIT:

In the interest of completeness, the way to do this *without* `defaultdict` would be as follows:

```
e = {}
for email in Emails:
    case = email.get('CaseNumber')
    if not case in e:
        # create single element list if key not in dictionary
        e[case] = [email]
    else:
        e[case].append(email)
```

In more shorthand, you can use `get` to avoid `KeyErrors` entirely:

```
for email in Emails:
    case = email.get('CaseNumber')
    e[case] = e.get(case, []).append(email)
```

Where `get` will return either the value associated with `case` or a default value specified as the second argument (which is a `list` here)